# Описание правки при ее утверждении

Tags: предложение, предлагаемые-правки

Если предлагаемая правка полезна, но содержит по мнению проверяющего некоторые дефекты, то правильный способ - это выбрать <kbd>Применить и улучшить</kbd>, внести нужные исправления и применить.

Однако, замечено, что в этом случае в поле "Описание правки" копируется текст, который внес туда предлагающий правку. При этом улучшения правки, как правило, содержат несколько иные действия (например, улучшение правописания, или изменение меток), а так как упомянутое поле часто бывает просто не используют, получается, что в ревизию попадает две правки с одинаковым описанием. [Пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/571171/revisions):

[image: изменен заголов]

Если бы при улучшении правки поле "Описание правки" было пустое, то в резолюцию бы попал автосгенерированный текст, типа:

> Изменен заголовок вопроса.

или

> В текст добавлено 2 символа.

Это было бы куда лучше, чем разные правки с одинаковым описанием, тем более, когда в одной из них это описание не соответствует действительности.